# At what point does passphrase strength match the strength of the cipher?

Tags: aes

Let's say that I have an ordinary hard drive encrypted with VeraCrypt 1.0e full disk encryption and implementing:

-AES

-RIPEMD-160 Hash Algorithm

Now let's say that for an arbitrary machine, the amount time that it takes to make 1 guess at the master encryption key itself is equal to 1 unit of time. (I understand that, in practical terms, it is beyond infeasible to attempt to crack the master encryption key of AES-256. This is a purely theoretical question.) Knowing that VeraCrypt uses 327,661 iterations of PBKDF2-RIPEMD-160, how many units of time would it take to check 1 *password*?

What I am interested to know is, at what point K, where K is the *keyspace* of the randomly generated *password*, does the strength of the password match the strength of the cipher itself, knowing that the former will have to been run through 327,661 iterations of PBKDF2-RIPEMD-160 to arrive at the latter, where an equivalence of strength is defined as an equivalence of the amount of time that, on average, a brute-force attack would take.

Assuming that the amount of time that it would take for 1 iteration of PBKDF2 to occur = the amount of time that it would take to make 1 check at the master encryption key itself (which I DO NOT simply assume to be a correct assumption), then 327,661 iterations adds log(327661)/log(2) = 18.3 bits of entropy to the overall "strength" of the passphrase. It seems that finding an answer to my question would yield the logical upper-limit of password strength, the point after which it makes no sense to use a [password + key derivation function] whose average time to crack is longer than that of the cipher master encryption key itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long passwords and key derivation functions](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74566/long-passwords-and-key-derivation-functions)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not missing some important point here, that's rather trivial to calculate. As implicitly stated in your question, the attacker has two possible ways to brute-force the encryption key: either by brute-forcing the encryption key itself or by brute-forcing the user-entered password.

Given the numbers of iterations of the key derivation function *n*, the time per kdf iteration *t<sub>kdf</sub>*, the length of the encryption key *b* (in bits) and the time per invocation of the actual encryption algorithm *t<sub>enc</sub>*, the average time needed to crack the encryption key itself (by testing half of the available keyspace) is

1/2⋅2<sup>*b*</sup>⋅*t<sub>enc</sub>*.

The average time to crack the user-entered password is

1/2⋅*K*⋅(*n*⋅*t<sub>kdf</sub>+t<sub>enc</sub>*),

with *K=c<sup>l</sup>* being the entirety of all passwords available to the user (*c*: number of characters available, *l*: length of password).

In your scenario, *t<sub>enc</sub>*=*t<sub>kdf</sub>*=1, and *n*=327661. Assuming AES-256 is used (*b*=256), one has to solve the equation

1/2⋅2<sup>*b*</sup>⋅*t<sub>enc</sub>* = 2<sup>256</sup> = *K*⋅327662 = 1/2⋅*K*⋅(*n*⋅*t<sub>kdf</sub>+t<sub>enc</sub>*),

which yields (approximately) *K*=5.9447⋅10<sup>35</sup>. Assuming an available keyspace of 90 characters (which most users aren't likely to even find on their keyboards), this translates to approximately *l*=36.

(Disclaimer: I'm neither a mathematician nor an crypto expert. In case of any mathematical or semantic error, please comment.)

Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74566/long-passwords-and-key-derivation-functions